# Does someone know how to make a full screen title bar get zoomed without loosing the title from the center

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to make a portfolio with a responsive design. I wanted to make a title bar that occupies all the screen to then scroll down and go to the content. I've got that using the grid and justifying and aligning the content (and using some padding). It is responsive but if one zooms enough the title goes down and leaves the screen view. I would like to know if someone could help me with it. I want it to stay in the center while zooming. I share what I've written. Have a nice day guys.

```css
*{
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    font-family: helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
}
/*-------------------HEADER AND MENU BAR----------------------*/
body{
    background:white;   
}
#Title{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(20px, 3fr 1fr);
    padding: 0px;
    max-width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color:whitesmoke;
    background-image: linear-gradient( to right, #9E0086,#FF5E00);
}
#Title > h1{
    padding: 400px 0px 400px 0px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    font-size: 25px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;
}
#Title > img{
    grid-column: 2/3;
    max-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
/*------------------SECTION AND ARTICLES------------------*/
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="MyPortfolio" content="MyPortfolio">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="Portfoliostyle.css">
        </head>
        <div>
            <body>
                <div >
                    <header id="Title">
                        <h1>
                            MY PORTFOLIO
                        </h1>
                        <img src="arrow.svg" alt="arrow">
                    </header> 
                </div>          
            </body>
        </div>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added full screen and used vw and vh for full height and width.

Hope this helps

```css
    *{
        padding:0px;
        margin: 0px;
        font-weight: lighter;
        box-sizing: border-box; 
        font-family: helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
    }
    /*-------------------HEADER AND MENU BAR----------------------*/
    body{
        background:white;   
    }
    #Title{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-auto-rows: minmax(20px, 3fr 1fr);
        padding: 0px;
        width: 100vw;
        height : 100vh;
        text-align: center;
        color:whitesmoke;
        background-image: linear-gradient( to right, #9E0086,#FF5E00);
    }
    #Title > h1{
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        font-size: 25px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    #Title > img{
        grid-column: 2/3;
        max-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
    }
```

```html
    <DOCTYPE! html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta name="MyPortfolio" content="MyPortfolio">
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="Portfoliostyle.css">
            </head>
            <div>
                <body>
                    <div >
                        <header id="Title">
                            <h1>
                                MY PORTFOLIO
                            </h1>
                            <img src="arrow.svg" alt="arrow">
                        </header> 
                    </div>          
                </body>
            </div>
        </html>
```

Comment: thanks! I will check right now and see how it works!